# Get minimum value of masked array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, mask

I have a masked array, from which I'd like to return the **index** of the **minimum value**.  Further, I'd like to return the index of a randomly chosen minimum if there are multiple.  In the example below, this should randomly return 
index `4` or `5`:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import random

my_mask = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
my_array = [ 0.018, 0.011, 0.004, 0.003, 0.0, 0.0]
masked_array = ma.masked_array(my_array,my_mask)

min_indices = np.where(masked_array.min() == masked_array)
min_index = np.random.choice(min_indices[0])

print masked_array
print min_index
```

**My problem**: The masked elements are treated as zero (?), and any element from  `{0,3,4,5}` can be returned.

**My question**: What is a good way to return the index of a (randomly chosen) minimum from an array (excluding masked values)?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `masked_array.min` does ignore the masked values. You actually have zeros in the valid portion of your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ma.where()` instead of `np.where()`

```
min_indices = ma.where(masked_array == masked_array.min()))
print(min_indices)
```

Which gives:

```
(array([4, 5]),)
```

The `ma` module has a lot of functions that are designed to work with masked arrays.

Finally, grabbing a random element from this result would be something like:

```
min_index = np.random.choice(min_indices[0])
```